# Django rest filters aggregation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

Here is my custom filter class

```
class CarFilter(FilterSet):
    pickup_date = NumberFilter(method='filter_pickup_date_timestamp')
    dropoff_date = NumberFilter(method='filter_dropoff_date_timestamp')

class Meta:
    model = Car
    fields = ['area_coverage', 'is_published', 'owner']

def filter_pickup_date_timestamp(self, queryset, name, value):
    pickup_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(value))
    for car in queryset:
        if len(Reservation.objects.filter(
            dropoff_date__gte=pickup_date,
            is_active=True,
            item_type='car',
            item=car.item,
        )) > 0:
            return None
    return queryset.filter()

def filter_dropoff_date_timestamp(self, queryset, name, value):
    dropoff_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(value))
    for car in queryset:
        if len(Reservation.objects.filter(
            pickup_date__lte=dropoff_date,
            is_active=True,
            item_type='car',
            item=car.item,
        )) > 0:
            return None
    return queryset.filter()
```

Is it possible to create such method, that will filter by both arguments `pickup_date` and `dropoff_date`? How to get `value` from another filter filed in method? Because know I have to filter through `Reservation` model twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, because in method request can be accessed through `self`

```
def filter_pickup_date_timestamp(self, queryset, name, value):
    pickup_date = value
    dropoff_date = self.request.query_params.get('dropoff_date')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You just have to do it like this:

```
Reservation.objects.filter(LOGIC_FOR_FIRST_FILTERING_HERE).filter(LOGIC_FOR_SECOND_FILTERING_HERE)
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question. How can I get `value` from different field in method?